# Why use const variables instead of preprocessor directives when programming embedded with C++

Tags: embedded, software, c++

I read on here that when programming with C++, const variables are better than preprocessor directives, ie #define, for declaring constants. I'm confused about why that is the case.

I understand that a const variable would be stored in static memory, whereas a preprocessor directive would become a literal, and possibly an immediate in assembly, but I don't see why that is a disadvantage.

I've also seen that inline functions are better than macros, but I'm confused about what is the difference.

Thanks!

Comment: For the same reason you use a box cutter with a 3mm knife tip instead of a katana to cut boxes. They do too much with too few restrictions. defines and macros are loose-cannons. Just doing a text replace is not as safe. Variable types exist for a reason. There are situations where the compiler complains about types not matching and I can't figure out a sufficiently simple way to force it so then I use defines to get around the compiler safeguards which shows you how unsafe they can be.

Comment: Read Bjarne Stroustrup's ["So, what's wrong with using macros?"](https://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#macro). He invented C++ and used *readonly* instead of *const* in early versions. (*readonly* came with a matching *writeonly* keyword, back in the day.)

Comment: For declaring constants as your question states the const will have a flash cost and possible performance cost over the #define. (which are both bad for embedded).  One can find possible pros and cons for both solution, there is no "best" way here.  Putting the constant in the code where it can be seen vs far away where it cannot is yet another solution that has pros and cons (but from a risk and code production perspective is the ideal solution).

Comment: @old_timer Modern C++ compilers do not reserve any memory space for static lifetime initialized const variables where their address is never taken anywhere else in the code. It type-checks, but otherwise treats them as if a literal. Only the parsing and lexical checking is different. So zero cost in flash. Now, if an address of the constant value is requested somewhere, then yes, space is now occupied because it must be if the constant is to have an address, at all. But if that's not done, C++ doesn't need to allocate space and a good C++ compiler tool chain will not do so.

Comment: The answer completely depends on which processor architecture you are targeting, as there is no single class of embedded C++ environment. Using consts on a 100MHz 32-bit ARM microcontroller might be something you should not even think about, but using consts on a low-end 8-bit MCUs such as PIC16F84 or ATTiny85 might be something you have to carefully investigate how the compiler decides to waste resources.

Comment: I think this question is a better fit for stackoverflow.com, where it's been asked quite a few times over the years. Here's one answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6442372/66490

Comment: Simply put, because they have *all* of the advantages with *none* of the disadvantages.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using a `const` value lets the compiler do some type checking, but a value you assign with a `#define` is just used for text substitution so all sorts of unexpected problems can occur.

Regardless of how you define constants, a good compiler should never store them as static values in RAM. A good compiler will often optimize them to immediate values embedded in the instructions themselves or literal values in the literal pool. For an embedded system running out of flash memory the literal pool would also remain in flash and would not take space in RAM.

Similarly for macros vs. inline functions. A macro does text substitution in the preprocessor and can easily lead to unintended consequences if you are not careful. If you don't look at the preprocessor output directly it can be hard to find and debug problems with macros. An inline function, on the other hand, provides the same functional capability as a macro but is easier for the compiler to check and easier to debug if necessary.

Comment: Just an addendum, nothing more. In some Harvard architecture cases, there exist no simple instructions that can read from flash/otp. (In a case or two, it cannot even be done at all and so some hardware mods are used to compensate.) So, often, the toolchain is arranged to reserve equal space in RAM and, prior to starting main(), to copy from flash into RAM. This is most particularly necessary for static-lifetime initialized, writable variables (not a constant, granted, but just the same yet annother issue to be coped with.) So literal constants may very well take up space in RAM. Just a note.

Comment: pure harvard is textbook only, most are "modified" harvard which is the same as saying "modified" von neumann, with one having the perception of being better than the other when there is no difference.  it is very difficult to compile for pure harvard, cant have an operating system, etc.  It is true though that const and pure/textbook harvard have issues, so you would have to use #defines or just put the constant in the line of code.

Comment: defines can land in the literal pool or in the instruction, const's have to be allocated space, and may require a memory access where a define might not.  wasting space and performance is not good for embedded.  There is no right answer here you have to write good code either way both have pros and cons. simple #define x 0x1234 and const int x = 0x1234, which is the question here, one has no more risk than the other, one has a performance and resource cost though.

Comment: when used for something other than constants, particularly macros then one does need to use care, but at the same time if you write bad code you write bad code no matter what solution you use, so the risk is minimal.

Comment: (the compiler for this textbook situation of pure harvard would have to put these items in ram, if it were a good compiler)

Comment: @old_timer, why do you think consts _have_ to be allocate space more than a literal has to?

Comment: @old_timer Any compiler worth the name would treat a `const` just like a `#define` constant in terms of storage. Why would it not?

Comment: Re: type checking vs. text substitution -- this is a common misunderstanding. The type of `1` is `int`; the type of `1.1` is `double`. There's no ambiguity there. Creating that text with a macro doesn't change that.

Comment: Ah okay this makes it clear to me, thank you. The big thing I was missing was that a good compiler will treat const variables like literals so that they don't take up memory space. By good compiler you mean like industry standard right? like gcc could be expected to do this?

Comment: @old_timer,  systems where it is not possible to read program memory and data memory with the same instructions are certainly not textbook only, though I don't know if any of them supported C++.

Comment: @PeterGreen Would [this alignment stuff](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PROGMEM.html) on ESP8266/ESP32 count?

Comment: @PeterGreen reading program memory and data memory with the same instructions is not what harvard is. harvard is completely separate instruction and data busses, so that the instruction fetches do not interfere with the data operations making things more efficient. but this means, no bootloaders, no operating systems, etc without cheating in some way.What you see in reality marketing will call "modified harvard" and those end up being instruction and data share the same bus with maybe a control bit to indicate a clock cycle is one or the other. but that is also called not-modified von neumann.

Comment: someone read a book that implied that harvard was better so best to say modified harvard rather than actual von neumann in the documentation or marketing literature....It makes no sense to bring up harvard in discussions like these as it truly is only a classroom thought exercise and not something you really have to deal with.  And if someone did force that then you have a long list of nightmares to deal with and this topic of const vs define is completely irrelevant to your task.

Answer (score 6):

`static const` values respect the scope of `namespace` and `class` — `#define` doesn't.

If the value is not a POD, then a `static const` will only have one instance of it, at least per compilation unit (.cpp file), a `#define` will be instantiated at each use. The compiler may (or may not) merge each compilation unit's usage together, if it can guarantee the constructor is `pure` (ie it has not side effects).

Comment: No, a `#define`d value is not unconditionally instantiated when used. Its name is just replaced with its value in the source code, before the compiler decides what to do with it.

Comment: +1 , because in my opinion the namespace issue is the biggest unavoidable drawback to #define . There are some unexpected-effect issues with #define, to be sure, but standard C/C++ programming idioms can prevent those. Polluting the namespace, you can't fix.   That said I still use #define's liberally :-/

Comment: Thank you! What does POD stand for?

Comment: @Dyskord -- POD = Plain Old Data, or *standard layout* in C++11 and newer -- some aggregate which is guaranteed to be laid out in a C-compatible fashion, basically